# Angularjs: update select options

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have two select menus . One for country selection and other for state. I need to update states based country selected. I am able to log states but not able to list them in select menu.Please help.

Angular:

```
angular.module('demoApp', []).controller('DemoController', function($scope) {
$scope.countries = [
    { label: 'Please select', value: 0 },
    { label: 'India', value: 1 },
    { label: 'US', value: 2 }
];

$scope.data = [{'1':[{ label: 'Delhi', value: 0 },{ label: 'Mumbai', value: 1 },{ label: 'Chennai', value: 2 }]},
                {'2':[{ label: 'Alabama', value: 3 },{ label: 'Alaska', value: 4 },{ label: 'Arizona', value: 5 }]}];

$scope.vm = {states: []};                                              

$scope.updateStates = function(countryCode){
    $scope.vm.states = $scope.data[countryCode-1];
    console.log($scope.vm.states);
};

$scope.correctlySelected = $scope.countries[0];
});
```

HTML:

```
<body ng-app="demoApp">
    <div ng-controller="DemoController">
        <select ng-model="correctlySelected" ng-change="updateStates(correctlySelected.value)" ng-options="opt as opt.label for opt in countries">
        </select>
        <select ng-options="opt as opt.label for opt in vm.states">
        </select>
    </div>
</body>
```

JS Bin:
http://jsbin.com/pafosewedo/1/edit?html,js,console,output

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to add `ng-model` to your states `<select>` - this is required when you are using `ng-options`

You also have an inconvenient model for the states data. Each element of the data array that corresponds to the country's states is an object with a changing key whose value is an array of states. You *could* make it work, but it's better to change it to something more reasonable:

```
$scope.data = {
  1: [{ label: 'Delhi', value: 0 }, {...}, ],
  2: [{...}, {...}, ] // same for US
}
```

Then it would work with how you specified your `ng-options` for states, and you wouldn't have to deal with indices:

```
$scope.updateStates = function(countryCode){
    $scope.vm.states = $scope.data[countryCode]; // access by property
};
```

Comment: @ New Dev : Thanks for quick help. I updated code as you suggested and it answers my question. Now the state list gets populated but when I select any state it gets blank. Please suggest whats wrong there. see http://jsbin.com/sudajafira/1/edit?html,js,output

Comment: @Triven, that is because your `ng-model` on the state `select` is `vm` - which overwrites `vm.states` - where you are pulling your states from. Just change it to something else, like: `vm.selectedState`

Answer (score 1):

I think, that you should use some filter like that if you don't want to change your model:

```
.filter('stateFilter', function() {
  return function(states, countryID) {
    var filtered = [];

    angular.forEach(states, function(state){
        if(state.value === countryID)
            filtered.push(state);
    });

    return filtered;
  };
});
```

to filter out all values that have value equal to selected country.value in first select control.

To use that filter you need to modify your ng-repeat directive value in state select control:

```
ng-options="state as state.label for data | stateFilter:correctlySelected"
```

Answer (score 1):

I came up with the following solution, view my [JSBin](http://jsbin.com/yocijofeki/1/edit)

This solutions works by setting the countryCode in the scope when we are updatingStates.

```
$scope.updateStates = function(countryCode){
    $scope.countryCode = countryCode;
    $scope.vm.states = $scope.data[countryCode-1];
    console.log($scope.vm.states[countryCode]);
};
```

This change is then reflected in the view.

```
<select>
    <option ng-repeat='i in vm.states[countryCode]'> {{i.label}}
    </option>
</select>
```